# How can I find a ratio of sound pressures of two sounds recorded in two normalized wav files?

Tags: audio

I have two .wav files which contain recordings of the same sound measured by two mics located at different positions. The .wav file contain normalized sound levels(amplitude is in the range from -1 to 1). I would like to find the ratio of sound pressures (p1/p2) if it is possible. The sampling rate in both mics is the same (1 kHz).

Comment: What language, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am using MATLAB, and compared the ratio RMS_1/RMS_2, but the result does not make sense, since the mic which is closer gives lower sound pressure.